# How to pass primary key ID instead of attribute value into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a input box where the user enters in a zip code. I created an auto-suggest function that recommends zip codes based on the ones i have store in my database. Right now I linked it so the actual value of the zip code rather than the primary key. I am not sure how I can pass my primary key into my PHP file rather than the actual value.

HTML:

```
<div class="label">Zip Code:</div><br>
    <input type="text" id = "zip_id" class="tftextinput2" autocomplete = "off" name="zip" placeholder="Please enter your Zip Code" onkeyup = "autocomplete()">
    <ul id = "zip_codes_list_id"></ul>
```

JS:

```
function autocomplete() 
{
    var min_length = 1; 
    var keyword = $('#zip_id').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#zip_codes_list_id').show();
                $('#zip_codes_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#zip_codes_list_id').hide();
    }
}
function set_item(item) 
{
    // change input value
    $('#zip_id').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#zip_codes_list_id').hide();
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    //connect to db here
    $keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM zip_codes WHERE zip LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY zip_codes_id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $list = $query->fetchAll();
    foreach ($list as $rs) 
    {
        // put in bold the written text
        $zip = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['zip']);
        // add new option
        echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['zip']).'\')">'.$zip.'</li>';
    }
?>
```

From here I could do a POST request in my php file and i would store the actual zip code that the user entered. I however want to store the primary key associated with that zip code.

Comment: you could pass the id in an html attribute for the <li> element or the <input> value element, at your convenience

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($list as $rs) 
        {
            // put in bold the written text
            $zip = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['zip']);
            // add new option
            echo '<li " onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['primary_key_column_name']).'\')">'.$zip.'</li>';
        }
```

Comment: the JS post code should be modified as well, of course, for the value to be sent to the server (that's what OP is asking for btw).

Comment: Where would i edit the JS code? I tried using the data attribute, but when I tested it by echoing the zip value it still posted the zip code and not the primary key.

Comment: That works except I dont want to replace the value displayed with the primary key. Is there anyway I can display the attribute but when the user presses submit, the primary key is passed in?

Comment: Here the zip code will be the displayed value as you expected. What is the problem?